# How do I fix my if statements not repeating based on a random number generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a quiz game that alternates between asking for capital cities and countries. They are supposed to alternate randomly thus I am using a random number generator however the if statements wont repeat according to the output of the random number generator. (I'm pretty new to coding, sorry if this is long)

This is the code:

```
import random
from random import randrange

quest_one = int(input('How many questions? '))

for i in range(quest_one):
    number = (randrange(2))



Country_main = {
    "Australia" : 'Canberra',
    'india' : 'New Delhi',
    'France' : 'Paris',
    'Japan' : 'Tokyo',
    'China': 'Beijing',
    'USA': 'Washington',
    'England': 'London',
    'Russia': 'Moscow',
    'Germany': 'Berlin',
    'Brazil': 'Brasilia',
    'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'
}

Capital_main = {
    'Canberra': 'Australia',
    'New Delhi': 'India',
    'Paris': 'France',
    'Tokyo': 'Japan',
    'Beijing': 'China',
    'Washington': 'USA',
    'London': 'England',
    'Moscow': 'Russia',
    'Berlin': 'Germany',
    'Brasilia': 'Brazil',
    'Dhaka': 'Bangladesh'
}

def Capital_of():
    rando = random.choice(list(Country_main.items()))
    ans = input("What is the capital city of " + rando[0] + '? ')
    if rando[1] in ans:
        print('correct')
        #Change to add value to score later
    elif rando[1] not in ans:
        print('wrong')
    return


def Country_of():
    randy = random.choice(list(Capital_main.items()))
    ansy = input("Which country has the capital city " + randy[0] + '? ')
    if randy[1] in ansy:
        print('correct')
        # Change to add value to score later
    elif randy[1] not in ansy:
        print('wrong')
    return



if number == 1:
    Capital_of()
if number == 0:
    Country_of()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in the way you have your code structured.  Your `for` loop should be the main loop that asks the specified number of questions.

The way you have it setup right now, the for loop is generating `x` amount of random numbers and then it exits the loop and runs the rest of the program.

```
# current program

for i in range(quest_one):
    number = (randrange(2))

#
# more code
#

if number == 1:
    Capital_of()
if number == 0:
    Country_of()
```

Your `if` statements need to be nested inside of the `for` loop inorder to keep asking questions.

I reformatted your code so the `if` statement is nested in the `for` loop.
Try this out:

```
import random
from random import randrange

Country_main = {
    "Australia" : 'Canberra',
    'india' : 'New Delhi',
    'France' : 'Paris',
    'Japan' : 'Tokyo',
    'China': 'Beijing',
    'USA': 'Washington',
    'England': 'London',
    'Russia': 'Moscow',
    'Germany': 'Berlin',
    'Brazil': 'Brasilia',
    'Bangladesh': 'Dhaka'
}

Capital_main = {
    'Canberra': 'Australia',
    'New Delhi': 'India',
    'Paris': 'France',
    'Tokyo': 'Japan',
    'Beijing': 'China',
    'Washington': 'USA',
    'London': 'England',
    'Moscow': 'Russia',
    'Berlin': 'Germany',
    'Brasilia': 'Brazil',
    'Dhaka': 'Bangladesh'
}


def main():
    num_questions = int(input('How many questions? '))

    for i in range(num_questions):
        number = (randrange(2))

        if number == 1:
            capital_of()
        else:
            country_of()


def capital_of():
    rando = random.choice(list(Country_main.items()))
    ans = input("What is the capital city of " + rando[0] + '? ')
    if rando[1] in ans:
        print('correct')
        #Change to add value to score later
    elif rando[1] not in ans:
        print('wrong')
    return


def country_of():
    randy = random.choice(list(Capital_main.items()))
    ansy = input("Which country has the capital city " + randy[0] + '? ')
    if randy[1] in ansy:
        print('correct')
        # Change to add value to score later
    elif randy[1] not in ansy:
        print('wrong')
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```